# offsetTop of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the Following Script and when on my website, I keep receiving this error that says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of undefined
```

```js
// mouse-scroll

(function() {
    var delay = false;

    $(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(delay) return;

        delay = true;
        setTimeout(function(){delay = false},200)

        var wd = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;

        var a= document.getElementsByTagName('section');
        if(wd < 0) {
            for(var i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
                var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
                if(t >= 40) break;
            }
        }
        else {
            for(var i = a.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
                var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
                if(t < -20) break;
            }
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: a[i].offsetTop
        });
    });
})();
```

Comment: Use the debugger to figure out what is undefined and why.

Comment: your animate code is outside of loop. How can you get a[i] outside loop?

Comment: @SLaks I used it and it doesn't give say anything other than the error already mentioned.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati Could you be more specific please? Could you show me how i can fix this?

Comment: @Guille i think your `i` is set to -1 after loop in else ,check it's value in console before calling animate

Comment: @Ramanlfc hmm.. interesting.. i still cant figure it out. I am still learning js.. this is the site i am having issues with. [SITE](http://resume.justthingsido.com). Do you mind taking a look?

Comment: do a `console.log(i)` before calling `animate` , check the value it returns in console

Comment: @Ramanlfc I updated my source code so that the `console.log(i)` show on you side.. Could you check it.. Its kind of hard to explain the log i am seeing. and its much faster than uploading a picture

Comment: @Guille i only get an error in console, replace the call to `animate` for a second and just put `console.log(i)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98052/discussion-between-guille-and-ramanlfc).

Comment: @Ramanlfc update source code. you can see it on your side now.